# TensorFlow: storing distortions in graph definition

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Below I have some code that I use to deploy trained TensorFlow models. It basically just loads the model from a .pb file, gets the first and last layer of the model and evaluates an image. This works well, but I want to deploy many models with different image dimensions and distortions such as blurring, whitening and rotations.

My question is this: can image distortion sequences be stored inside .pb files? If so, how?

The goal is to minimize the amount of code in the deploy script.

```
import base64
import math
import os
import tensorflow as tf

def get_graph():
    if os.path.isfile('./graph.pb'):
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        with open('./graph.pb', 'rb') as graph_file:
            graph_def.ParseFromString(graph_file.read())
    else:
        raise Exception('Graph file \'./graph.pb\' does not exist')
    return graph_def

def init(event):
    graph_def = get_graph()

    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.graph.as_default()
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name = '')

        stringified = base64.b64decode(event['image'].split(',')[1])
        decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(stringified, channels = 3)
        decoded.set_shape([event['height'], event['width'], 3])
        image = tf.cast(decoded, tf.float32)

        evaluation = image.eval(sessions = sess)

        input_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_placeholder:0')
        output_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax_linear/softmax_linear:0')

        feed_dict = { input_tensor: evaluation }
        result = sess.run([output_tensor], feed_dict = feed_dict)
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how the original `graph.pb` was generated.

If you have modify the script that produced the original `graph.pb`, you can simply add your reshaping, distortions etc. operations to that script and regenerate the `graph.pb`. Note that you have to remove the old `input_placeholder` operation and connect to output of your preprocessing operations to the input of the operation that `input_placeholder` was feeding. Your new placeholder will then simply take `stringified` as input.

If you cannot modify the script that produced the original `graph.pb`, then you can reduce the amount of code in your deploy script by saving the preprocessing subgraph into a `.pb` of it's own. Something like :

```
raw_input = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(raw_input, channels = 3)
decoded.set_shape([event['height'], event['width'], 3])
image = tf.cast(decoded, tf.float32)
with open('preprocess.pb', 'w') as f:
  f.write(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())
```

You can then feed the raw input to your preprocessing subgraph, and feed the output (obtained still via an `eval` call) of that to your original graph.